# How to have all the exceptions thrown in the Mono context when using Spring reactive WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

#### Code

I have a Spring reactive web client used to connect to a web service.

```java
@Autowired
private org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient webClient;

public Mono<MyData> getMyData(MyRequest request) {
    return webClient
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> this.createUri(uriBuilder, request))
        // Any exception thrown before this point is outside of the Mono context
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(MyDataDto.class)
        .map(myDataDto -> mapToMyData(myDataDto))
        ;
}
```

There is a possibility that the `createUri()` method throws an exception:

```java
private URI createUri(UriBuilder uriBuilder, MyRequest request) {
    if (somethingIsInconsistent) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the exception is thrown in the main thread when the `Mono` is created, and not in the context of the `Mono` when it is subscribed.

#### Tests

As a result, the following test fails:

```java
@Test
void getMyData_whenBadRequest_throwExceptionWhenSubscribed() {
    service.getMyData(badRequest)
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectError(MyException.class)
        .verify();
}
```

and this passes:

```java
@Test
void getMyData_whenBadRequest_throwExceptionWhenCreated() {
    assertThrows(MyException.class, 
        () -> service.getMyData(badRequest));
}
```

I'd like to catch all the exception in the context of the `Mono` subscription.

#### Question

Is there some nice reactive `WebClient` idiom to wrap the call so **all** exceptions are thrown when the `Mono` is subscribed? All I came with is

```java
public Mono<MyData> getMyData(MyRequest request) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> this.createUri(uriBuilder, req))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MyDataDto.class)
         )
        .map(myDataDto -> mapToMyData(myDataDto))
        ;
}
```

but this looks to me awkward and ugly. The original code was much smoother and more easily readable!

The question is **not** *why* it happens. I know that it happens because that exception occurs as the `RequestHeaderSpec` is being built.

The URI is created dynamically, depending on the `request` input parameter. Some combination of fields of the `request` is not able to produce a valid URL and such a request should fail. I cannot think of a better place to create the URI. The most logical place seems the method itself. Even if I delegated the URI creation to an external class, it would be called before the `Mono` when the `RequestHeaderSpec` is being built.

Comment: Nope, there isn't because that exception has nothing to do with the subscription; it happens as the RequestHeaderSpec is being built.  I would rethink that design a little; building the URI shouldn't be throwing exceptions, and if there's a case where it would, it should be handled before it's time to build the WebClient.

Comment: @lane.maxwell See my edit. I *do* know that it happens as the RequestHeaderSpec is being built, I am wondering how to elegantly wrap it. I have no idea how to redesign the code, as the URI depends on the request, and although of course I check the request consistency before calling the method, still I need to have a low-level check here. The URI is created dynamically and cannot be created ahead.

Comment: "Elegant" is opinionated. In such case, the only improvement I personnally see is using a method reference instead of a multiline lambda. I woud keep the original method, but private, like `private Mono<MyData> getMyDataImpl(MyRequest request) { webClient.get... }`. Then, make the public method like that: `public Mono<MyData> getMyData(MyRequest request) { return Mono.just(request).flatMap(MyService::getMyDataImpl); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with an "all-in-the-Mono-stream" solution like this:

```java
public Mono<MyData> getMyData(MyRequest request) {
    return Mono.just(webClient)
            .map(WebClient::get)
            .map(uriBuilder -> this.createUri(uriBuilder, request))
            .map(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec::retrieve)
            .map(responseSpec -> responseSpec.bodyToMono(MyDataDto.class))
            .map(myDataDto -> mapToMyData(myDataDto))
    ;
}
```

In contrast to my previous solution from the original question, this one is more "flat", it is only one non-indented Mono fluent stream.